# How to access from state another key inside the state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to learn React and I have an issue. I want to make an example myself from the tutorial.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    persons: [],
    firstPersons: 5,
    variables: {
      Id: '1',
      first: this.firstPersons,
      input: {},
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log('this.state', this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Hello React!!!</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

I put in render method a `console.log(this.state)`.

I have this simple state in my page, and when I run the project I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstPersons' of undefined
```

Please someone tell me what is wrong on my code?

Comment: The object is not yet created so you cannot reference it. You could set a variable to hold the value you want and re-use it. `const firstPersons = 5;` and then use something like this `state = { firstPersons: firstPersons , variables: {first:firstPersons}}`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I cant put a const above the render method. Because the state is in the render() and from what I saw we can define a const between render() and return().

Comment: when you assign state, `first: this.firstPersons` was invalid

Comment: @JohnSmith please add some more surrounding code to your original so i can tell you where exactly to put the decleration.

Comment: can you add your babel configuration as well to see how you are transpiling the code ? also its better to define `firstPersons` either using const or let or define it in constructor of your class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access the object inside of itself in JS. You should do:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

var myVar = 5;

class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    persons: [],
    firstPersons: myVar,
    variables: {
      Id: '1',
      first: myVar,
      input: {},
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log('this.state', this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Hello React!!!</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

or

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    persons: [],
    firstPersons: 5,
    variables: {
      Id: '1',
      input: {},
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.state.variables.first = this.state.firstPersons;
    this.setState(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    console.log('this.state', this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Hello React!!!</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

or if componentWillMount() is deprecated

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    persons: [],
    firstPersons: 5,
    variables: {
      Id: '1',
      input: {},
    }
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    this.state.variables.first = this.state.firstPersons;
    this.setState(this.state);
  }


  render() {
    console.log('this.state', this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Hello React!!!</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: I'm sorry my friend, but how you put a var/const/let in a class component, above the render() and you don't get an error? I tried the 1st solution and I get an error that I can't put a variable there. The 2nd solution I  don't see how to use it because I get the same error that I can't use state.something... above render method :(

Comment: You didn't understand the idea. I did rewrite my answer to explain, check it please.

Var/const/let could be defined even before class, in your case I don't see any problems with that.
Also you can update state with using setState() method inside componentWillMount() to update your state before rendering.

Comment: It's good example, the second one, but plese change the componentWillMount  with a different method, because I get and error that is no longer used, because is deprecated my friend.

Comment: WARNING! To be deprecated in React v17. Use new lifecycle static getDerivedStateFromProps instead.

Comment: Ok, if you use react 17, just try getDerivedStateFromProps() instead of componentWillMount(), check my updated response. Not sure, because I have never used getDerivedStateFromProps before, but following documentation it should work

Comment: The approach works fine but the only modification I want to point is that we should declare variable declaration (var myVar = 5;) inside the class. I am getting error if I declare it outside class but once it's moved inside of class, it works like charm.

Thanks for suggesting this.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you this syntax :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
     persons: [],
     firstPersons: 5,
     variables: {
     Id: '1',
       first: this.firstPersons,
       input: {},
     }
  }

  render() {
   console.log('this.state', this.state);
   return (
      <div>
        <p>Hello React!!!</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: You can't access the object inside of itself in JavaScript. Your example doesn't work.